# "__globals__" getting merged when using decorators?

Tags: python

In the code below, `func2` seems to have the `__globals__` of `func1` + also the symbols from `contextlib`. Can anyone elaborate how this `globals` merging works? IE, does it merge `__dict__`'s of all modules involved in defining the function? Also, what happens when there's a name conflict?

```
import contextlib

def func1():
    pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def func2(args):
  pass


globals1 = set(func1.__globals__.keys())
globals2 = set(func2.__globals__.keys())

globals2.difference(globals1)    

{'GeneratorContextManager',
 '__all__',
 '__file__',
 'closing',
 'contextmanager',
 'nested',
 'warn',
 'wraps'}
```

Using Python 2.7.10

Comment: What makes you think it has both?

Comment: because if I take set difference of two sets of __globals__ I see symbols from `contextlib.py` in the second, updated question

Comment: That only shows that `func1.__globals__`  does not have those contextlib names; it doesn't show that `func2.__globals__` *does* have `func1` (and in fact it does not).

Comment: ok, good point, I was assuming stuff comes in from globals, but it seems to be getting them from __closure__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function object will have `__globals__` giving a reference to the global namespace of the module where the function was defined.

In your example, `func1` is defined in your module and has the globals of that module.  You defined `func2` in your module, but the `contextmanager` decorator wraps your function with another function.  That wrapper function is defined in `contextlib`, so when the decorator replaces `func2` with the wrapped version, the resulting function has the globals of `contextlib`.  It does *not* have the globals of your module.

However, the wrapped function retains a reference to your original function, which still has the globals of your own module.  In your example this can be seen via `func2.__closure__[0].cell_contents`:

```
# func1 is not in func2's globals
>>> func2.__globals__['func1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    func2.__globals__['func1']
KeyError: u'func1'

# func1 is in the globals of the internally-stored wrapped version of func2
>>> func2.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__globals__['func1']
<function func1 at 0x0000000002B2B358>
```